# How to get embedded code of autoplay youtube video

Tags: html, youtube

I need to embed a video in my project and I need to have a code for that so that it do not display any suggested videos at the end, and I need it it to be autoplayed when the page launches.

[This is the URL of the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WCxuHDfyUo%29)

Can I get help in this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1WCxuHDfyUo?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

just uncheck the box that has "suggested videos" and then copy and paste the code and it should work fine.  Have a Blessed day.